# 要素のclassはどのようにして決めるか

Tags: css

消したい要素の上で右クリックして「検証」を選びます。
HTMLの要素が青枠で示され、さらにStylusに消したい要素を記述します。
`.entry-card-content {display: none;}`

その要素はdivに設定されているclass「entry-card-content」らしいですが、なぜ、`entry-card-content` となるのでしょうか。
`.entry-card-content` の代わりに他のコードを記述するとどうなるのでしょうか

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2):

> その要素はdivに設定されているclass「entry-card-content」らしいですが、なぜ、`entry-card-content` となるのでしょうか。

`class` 属性の値は、その**文書を作成した人物が決定**します。つまり、文書の作成者が「この要素には `entry-card-content` というクラス名を割り当てる」と決めています。

> `.entry-card-content` の代わりに他のコードを記述するとどうなるのでしょうか

他のクラス名を指定すると、もしそのクラス名を付与されている要素が存在するならば、それらの要素に対して stylus による装飾が適用されます。一方でそういった要素が存在しない場合は、何も起きません。

Comment: 目的はStylusに正しく記述することです。

＞class 属性の値は、その文書を作成した人物が決定
もし、その人がコード上間違った記述をしたらどうなるのでしょうか
."entry-card-content card-content e-card-content"とします。
これはStylusはコード記述上のミスでなにも反応はしません
私はentry-card-content card-content e-card-contentの範囲内であればいいと思いますが、いかがでしょうか。
疑似編集をする人は
.entry-card-contentと記述する人もいれば
.entry-card-content card-contentと記述する人もいます。

PS:Stylusの詳しい説明はここでは割愛させてください。

Comment: 文書の作成者がクラスセレクタとして無効な値を与えていた場合は、クラスセレクタは機能しません。「～の範囲内」の部分は、質問の意図がわかりませんでした。範囲内とはどういった意味でしょうか？

Comment: このブログの説明では
引用
HTMLの要素とそれに設定されているCSSが表示されます。今回はこのdiv要素を消すと仮定し、divに設定されているclass「entry-card-content」を消す、という記述をStylusにしてみます。
引用
Classの属性が
entry-card-content card-content e-card-content
という範囲があるのに、なぜentry-card-contentでしょうか。Stylusに適用するClassの属性が行頭だけであるという決まりみたいなものがあるのでしょうか。

Comment: 文書全体を実際に読んだわけではないので明確なことは言えませんが、カスタムスタイルシートを適用したい要素を特定するために `.entry-card-content` というセレクタを指定すれば十分だからではないでしょうか。